# oracle/ sql query to count no. of rows in table added every hour

Tags: database, oracle

I want query to count no. of rows added in table X every hour.
Table X contains column (Timestamp) with below format:
15-Mar-16 08.44.09.1000004450 -05:00

Comment: `GROUP BY TO_CHAR(YOUR_COLUMN,'HH24')` provided, you filter only one day's data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   COUNT(*),
         TRUNC( TIME_COLUMN, 'HH24' ) AS Hour
FROM     X
GROUP BY TRUNC( TIME_COLUMN, 'HH24' );
```